# Why won't my SOAP XML response deserialize in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

My soap service call is returning the following response:

```
<AssetList xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Assets" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Facets xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Business_Classes.Search"/>
  <Results/>
  <err i:nil="true"/>
  <offset>0</offset>
  <total>0</total>
</AssetList>
```

When I attempt to serialize this via:

```
        AssetList assets;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AssetList));
        assets = (AssetList)serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.Content)));
```

I get the following exception:

```
<AssetList xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Assets'> was not expected.
```

The `AssetList` object I am trying to deserialize to was automatically generated by updating my service reference against the same exact service I am calling with my GET request.

Why is this failing?

The AssetList class is generated as:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="AssetList", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Assets")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class AssetList : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private XOSDigital.XOSSuperfanAdminList.XosAssetWebService.AvailableFacetGroup[] FacetsField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private XOSDigital.XOSSuperfanAdminList.XosAssetWebService.Asset[] ResultsField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string errField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private int offsetField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private int totalField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public XOSDigital.XOSSuperfanAdminList.XosAssetWebService.AvailableFacetGroup[] Facets {
        get {
            return this.FacetsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.FacetsField, value) != true)) {
                this.FacetsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Facets");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public XOSDigital.XOSSuperfanAdminList.XosAssetWebService.Asset[] Results {
        get {
            return this.ResultsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ResultsField, value) != true)) {
                this.ResultsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Results");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string err {
        get {
            return this.errField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.errField, value) != true)) {
                this.errField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("err");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int offset {
        get {
            return this.offsetField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.offsetField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.offsetField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("offset");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int total {
        get {
            return this.totalField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.totalField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.totalField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("total");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the autogenerated AssetList class?

Comment: Updated the question with the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is related with namespaces.

Can you try this?

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AssetList),"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Assets");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this as the first line in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Also, add `XmlRoot` attribute with namespace to your `AssetList` class:

```
[XmlRoot("AssetList", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XOSDigital.Assets")]
```

Comment: Nope I still get teh same error at the same line (AssetList was not expected)